# Connection to layout renderer failed

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just installed Xamarin on my Visual Studio and opened a blank project so I could test the debugging for mobile. But when I open the activity_mail.xml the designer shows the following error:

"Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by misconfiguration of Java."

[image: Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by misconfiguration of Java.]

Initially, the SDK version was the default from Xamarin installation, but I've also tried to use version 1.8_231 and 1.7_80, with no success. I've also updated Android SDK to latest version, but also no success. The Android configuration page is set as following:

[image]

This is the log of the error:

```
[2020-01-13 17:51:33.7] INFO: : Android Designer version: 16.4.464 (4abf337c3)
[2020-01-13 17:51:40.2] INFO: : JDK version: 1.8.0-25
[2020-01-13 17:51:40.2] INFO: : JDK vendor: Microsoft
[2020-01-13 17:51:57.5] INFO: : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
[2020-01-13 17:51:57.5] INFO: :     at mono.android.HostProcessConnection.log(HostProcessConnection.java:92)
[2020-01-13 17:51:57.5] INFO: :     at mono.android.HostProcessConnection.logError(HostProcessConnection.java:69)
[2020-01-13 17:51:57.5] INFO: :     at mono.android.JniHelper.loadJniLibrary(JniHelper.java:25)
[2020-01-13 17:51:57.5] INFO: :     at mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.main(AndroidDesignerHost.java:44)
[2020-01-13 17:51:58.0] ERROR: : Connection failed
Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaProcessNotStartedException: Error at starting designer's Java process
   in Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaProcessConnection.<DoConnect>d__49.MoveNext() at E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Java\JavaProcessConnection.cs:line 176
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
```

Visual Studio also doesn't let me build the application.

How can I solve this issue?

Version info:
Xamarin.Essentials: 1.3.1

Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, .Support.CustomTabs and .Support.Core.Utils: 20.0.0.3

Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1

Android SDK platform-tools: 29.0.4

Android Sdk Build tools: 28.0.3

OS: Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: First of all , please create a new project, If this issue is still existed. If you install JDK1.6 or .17 ,please Uninstall Java JDK 1.6 and Java JDK 1.7 using the "Programs and Features" control panel. On Windows, Then,please close your VS delete the `bin` and `obj` in your project folders,  rebuild your project. If still have this issue, please click the `repair` in the VS installer.

Answer (score 0):

try to Install the “Desktop development with C++” workload will workaround this issue.